# Is there likely to be a market for private company incentive equity if it's assessed value is more than it's worth?

Tags: options, employee-stock-options

Let's say I have some stock options in my company that I can exercise for $x.  And the company's value has been assessed by some external entity to revalue the stock to $x+y.  The company is still private, but these have (supposedly) intrinsic value, right?  So should there be a market for such a thing (e.g. is there?).  Or if I purchase, will they just remain in my broker / Carta / whatever entity holds the options?

Answer (score 6):

It depends on the company charter. Some companies allow employees trading their shares in what is called ["over the counter" (OTC) market](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Over-the-counter_(finance)). Not all companies allow that, some companies do not allow shares transfer without their prior approval. You'll need to check with your company what their policy is.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, though the actual mechanics depend on your company. Very few private companies allow OTC sales. They may occasionally have a tender offer, during a capital raise, to give employees the opportunity for some liquidity by having their institutional shareholders purchase directly from employees, or by doing a stock buyback.

For early-stage employees who wanted to get liquidity from my previous job’s shares, there were a lot of salespeople trawling LinkedIn trying to offer that service for you. The way it works is they give you a loan, with the shares as collateral, and a contract that you will transfer the shares to them as soon as there is the ability to do so. You will not get as much money as in a private sale or a tender offer! But that discount is the price you pay for this bespoke lending process. Be very sure you understand the contract.